# the speed of camera rotations when using the numbers of the numpad?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

is there a way to lower the speed of the rotation when pressing 2 4 6 8 in the numpad for a quick camera rotation around an object ?  A way without scripting. Maybe changing the start up file or something like that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, go to [User Preferences/Interface](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/interface.html), and here play with the Smooth View and Rotation Angle settings.

> **Smooth View**
>       Length of time the animation takes when changing the view with the numpad. Reduce to zero to remove the animation.
>
> **Rotation Angle**
>       Rotation step size in degrees, when Numpad4, Numpad6, Numpad8, or Numpad2 are used to rotate the 3D View.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Edit > Preferences > Navigation > Orbit & Pan**

**Rotation Angle** is the number of degrees the camera turns on each press on <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd>.

**Smooth View** is the inverse speed of the animation. A higher number will extend the time it takes for the rotation to complete, but a smaller rotation angle will reduce the time it takes for the rotation to complete.